# pdo_pgsql and php on mac os x yosemite

Tags: php, osx-yosemite

So I compiled pdo_pgsql from source and added the extension to my php.ini

```
phpinfo()
```

says

```
PDO

PDO support enabled
PDO drivers mysql, sqlite, pgsql

pdo_pgsql

PDO Driver for PostgreSQL   enabled
PostgreSQL(libpq) Version   9.4.2
Module version  1.0.2
```

but

```
pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=dbname user=username password=password")
```

gives

```
Call to undefined function pg_connect()
```

Yes, I did restart apache.

```
SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) PHP/5.5.20
```

I am on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Thanks!

Comment: I use the PDO constructor, like : self::$journal_pdo = new \PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=applog;charset=utf8' , $user , $pass); ...  DSN is 'pgsql' i think. try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about make your connection like so:

```
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=port-number;dbname=database','db-user','db-pass');

        $conn->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Yes that works. So whats up with the extension, why didn't it add the pg_connect functions?

Comment: I am still researching how pg_connect is deprecated. Will update once I get an answer.

Comment: At php link ... `The old syntax with multiple parameters $conn = pg_connect("host", "port", "options", "tty", "dbname") has been deprecated.`